# How to set session for user basing on time difference in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, analytics, data-mining

I have a dataframe with such a structure (ordered by user_id, time of event):

user_id
time of event (in milliseconds)
 
time difference between previous and current events for every user_id (in seconds)

For example 
user_1 1550844324011 - 
user_1 1550844504351 180

user_2 1550807681932 -  
user_2 1550807780002 98 
user_2 1550809800005 2020 
user_2 1550819800005 10000

And then i want to set session id for every user_id in a new column. The logics is next: if time difference between events is more than 900 seconds then i should set new session_id for user. So the result should be next:

user_1 1550844324011 - 1 
user_1 1550844504351 180 1

user_2 1550807681932 -  1 
user_2 1550807780002 98 1 
user_2 1550809800005 2020 2 
user_2 1550819800005 10000 3

How can i do that correctly? Help me please.
 Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```py
# Sorting is needed, otherwise .diff() will output wrong results
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'timestamp'])

# Timestamp diff in seconds
diff_timestamp = df.groupby('user_id')['timestamp'].diff() / 1000

# indexes where new session_id will be created
new_session = (diff_timestamp.isnull()) | (diff_timestamp > 900)

# Create unique session_id for every user
df['session_id'] = df.loc[new_session, ['user_id', 'timestamp']] \
    .groupby('user_id').rank(method='first').astype(int)

# Propagate last valid observation forward (replace NaN)
df['session_id'] = df['session_id'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
```

[image: Unique session ID by timestamp and user ID]

---

After a [small talk](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188956/discussion-between-robinfrcd-and-chick-chirik), if using `.diff()`, make sure the column is numeric!

Comment: Thank you for help! But there are problems with the second row "diff_timestamp = df.groupby('user_id').diff()['timestamp']". The error occurs

Comment: And there is an error with 'df['session_id'] = df[new_session].groupby('user_id').rank(method='first').astype(int)' - ''NoneType' object is not callable'. Can't understand the reason

Comment: Could you upload your dataset somewhere ? Which pandas version are you using ? `pd.__version__`

Comment: Uploaded sample of dataset there https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k865mUyiBd0ohhs5ezDxwgCmJ3qph6PP/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: Pandas version is 0.23

Comment: I added a .loc to handle the NaN values you have in the dataset you just gave, tell me if it's working now. :)

Comment: To be honest i'm stuck in the second row yet: diff_timestamp = df.groupby('user_id').diff()['timestamp'] / 1000. Getting an error 'timestamp'

Comment: Oh, I guess you don't have a `timestamp`column then. Make sure that the column where all your timestamps are stored is called `timestamp`.

Comment: The strange thing is that i have a such column. I guess there is a problem with syntax..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188956/discussion-between-robinfrcd-and-chick-chirik).